# AD / Windows authentication on Azure

Tags: php, authentication, iis, azure

I'm developing a REST service with PHP on IIS. During development, I tested it with IIS's Windows authentication on the domain controller and it worked fine and authenticated against the domain Active Directory. I was even able to limit the users to certain security groups.

Right now, I am trying to deploy this website to Windows Azure but I don't know how to get the authentication to work. I've been looking for a solution all week now but all I found are instructions on how to set up ADFS, AD Sync and Single sign on - none of which seem suitable.

My web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Allow" roles="SomeSecurityGroup" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst , on Windows Azure, you can deploy your site as a web role on a Virtual Network that has an Active directory deployed and use Windows Authentication pretty much in the same way as you would on-premises, you would be missing a trick as you would still have a fair amount of infrastructure to manage in the way of an Active Directory instance deployed on Azure and/or a Virtual Private Network (WPN) between Windows Azure and your Windows Azure Network.

They key then is, then, using either Windows Azure Active Directory, Windows Azure Access Control Service, or - frankly - any other WS-Federation based identity provider but basing your application on WS-federation rather than Kerberos tokens.

[This](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/web-sso/) article walks through the basics of using Windows Azure Active Directory from PHP and should point you in the right direction but basically the idea is to move toward WS-Federation and claims based authentication using known identity providers rather than relying on Windows Authentication which is not easily mapped to internet standards

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving some advice. I've stumbled across this very page once but came to the conclusion that it was outdated / not suitable. I'll have a closer look at it now and report back.